# Why my function returns true even if one of my conditions are wrong?

Tags: java, inheritance, boolean, logic

in Java I have two functions working together to return a boolean condition. Both are getting objects from a class Programa with inheritance classes Serie and Filme. They should return true only when the oject trying to being created have the same name + the same category + same class from one already existing, but when I have same name, with same category in other class, he still getting true.

Ex: name: Doe, category COMEDIA, Serie
I can't do "name: Doe, category COMEDIA, Filme"

You can see where I'm getting wrong?

```
    public boolean seExiste(Programa programa) {
        for (Programa y : this.programa) {
            if (Serie.class.isInstance(y) && y.getNome().equals(programa.nome)
                    && y.getCategoria().equals(programa.categoria)) {
                return true;
                
            } if (Filme.class.isInstance(y) && y.getNome().equals(programa.nome)
                    && y.getCategoria().equals(programa.categoria)) {
                return true;
            }                   
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
public void cadastrar(Programa programa) {
        if (!seExiste(programa)) {
            // System.out.println(programa.hashCode());
            this.programa.add(programa);
        } else {
            System.err.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your class fields are static?

Comment: nope, not static, protected like the others, but not static

Comment: I hate to state the obvious but you realize you will never return false inside the loop, right?  So if either if condition is satisfied you will return true.  Otherwise the loop will continue.

Comment: Yes @WJS , I saw your old comment and I'm trying to work with this, but I'm a student (2 weeks student), and I'm getting trouble to "think" in ways to return false and work. Because when I do a "else" with false return inside the loop, I still have the problem. I can create a object with same name and class, with other category, but I can't create with same name, same category and other class.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: rather than `Filme.class.isInstance(y)`, you can use `y instanceof Filme`. That said, are you attempting to exclude additions that the same, or different, types? In other words, we're definitely checking name and category, but do you want to allow a `Filme` and `Serie` with those same details, or prevent that?

Comment: It still isn't clear what you want to return.  It almost seems like a boolean isn't appropriate here.  That you want to return some indication for `Serie`, another for `Filme`, or a third possibility  if neither is found.

Comment: @Rogue I want to allow two diferent objects with Filme and Serie and the rest with same deatils. I want have Name 1, category X, Serie, and a second one Name 1, category Y, Serie. And a third one Name 1, category X, Filme. But this third one get the error from cadastrar().

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are doing. When you return true you will not know if it was `Filme` or `Serie`.  Perhaps you should return an `int` of 1,2 or -1 or use an `enum` to indicate what was evaluated.

```
public boolean seExiste(Programa programa) {
    for (Programa y : this.programa) {
        
        // here is the common condition.
        // this must be true to return true.
        // otherwise the loop continues. Notice the ! that inverts the expression.
        if (!(y.getNome().equals(programa.nome)
                && y.getCategoria().equals(programa.categoria))) {
            continue;  // skip next if and continue loop
        }
        // if the the categoria and nome match then check the instance.   
        if (Filme.class.isInstance(y) || Serie.class.isInstance(y)) {
            return true;
        }           
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there inheritance between Filme and Serie ? In this case, if a Serie is a Filme (Serie extends Filme) then Serie.class.isInstance(filmeObject) will be false always and Filme.class.isInstance(serieObject) will be true.

The [isInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method decides if the object (argument) is compatible with the class.

The dynamic type of the object is compatible with the Class (static type) if it extends it (static type is a class) or implements it (static type is an interface).